# Problems integrating jenkins with a public repo in github

Tags: java, jenkins, github

when ever I try to create a freestyle job on Jenkins the following happens

I added the GitHub project url: https://www.screencast.com/t/La4afGnl and saved the Job with an execution timer of 15 mins.

But every time that runs, it does successfully but when I look at the console output I get only this lines: 
Execute.on Workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test 4
Finished: SUCCESS

it seems that it is not loading the public repo from github and I have no clue on why.

Thanks in Advance to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the link which you have added will just provide a hyperlink to the GitHub repo in the Job. You can see a button added in your Job "GitHub".

So you need to add it in the SCM section(Source code Management)

1. select git
2. add Repository URL and Credentials if required.

   [image]

Hope it helps :)